# Apache Tomcat running on same server as IIS

Tags: iis-7, port, tomcat

I don't have much experience with servers at all so I was hoping someone could help me.

I've just started a job as a web developer and the server that the company has, has IIS 7  installed on it. I've currently been tasked with installing a piece of software that requires an apache tomcat installation.

Is it possible to run IIS and Tomcat side by side using different ports (not IP addresses) on the server? For example, only allowing Tomcat to use port 8080, and leave the rest to IIS?

Any help/advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sure is, just setup the port you want within the connector configuration. e.g. for configuring a tomcat http connector check [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html)

Comment: Also, I will note that you have the option of fronting that tomcat with the IIS instead of having them be completely separate, which may be helpful if you need more extensive functionality out of the HTTP layer.  See http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html on how to do that.